# Angular JS and passing complex object array as attribute to directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having trouble passing this complex object array through an attribute to a directive. What I am doing wrong and why is it wrong?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdvywqz9/)

Cut and pasted code

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <pass-object obj="obj"></pass-object>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('passObject', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { obj: '=' },
        template: '<div ng-repeat="foo in foos">Hello, {{foo.prop}}!</div></div>'
    };
});

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.obj = [{ prop: "hello" }, {prop: "world"}];
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are iterating over `foos` in your directive template. You didn't pass in foos, you passed in `obj`. Try this:

```
myApp.directive('passObject', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { obj: '=' },
        template: '<div ng-repeat="o in obj">Hello, {{o.prop}}!</div></div>'
    };
});
```

[Updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/rdvywqz9/2/)

Answer (score 3):

There is no scope property named `foos`, it should be `obj` according to your scope definition `scope: { obj: '=' }`:

```
template: '<div ng-repeat="foo in obj">Hello, {{foo.prop}}!</div></div>'
```

Or you can change scope config to:

```
scope: { foos: '=obj' },
```